# How to resize a tiff image with multiple channels?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-resizing, tiff

I have a tiff image of size 21 X 513 X 513 where (513, 513) is the height and width of the image containing 21 channels. How can I resize this image to 21 X 500 X 375?

I am trying to use PILLOW  to do so. But can't figure out if I am doing something wrong.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from tifffile import imread
>>> img = Image.open('new.tif')
>>> img

    <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=F size=513x513 at 0x7FB0C8E5B940>

>>> resized_img = img.resize((500, 375), Image.ANTIALIAS)
>>> resized_img

    <PIL.Image.Image image mode=F size=500x375 at 0x7FB0C8E5B908>

>>> resized_img.save('temp.tif')

>>> img = imread('temp.tif')
>>> img.shape
  (500, 375)
```

The channel information is lost here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `tifffile` and `scikit-image`:

```
from tifffile import imread, imwrite
from skimage.transform import resize

data = imread('2009_003961_SEG.tif')
resized_data = resize(data, (375, 500, 21))
imwrite('multi-channel_resized.tif', resized_data, planarconfig='CONTIG')
```

The file `2009_003961_SEG.tif` linked in [comment98601187_55975161](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974717/how-to-resize-a-tiff-image-with-multiple-channels/55975161#comment98601187_55975161) is not a multi-channel 513x513x21 image. Instead the file contains 513 images of size 513x21. The [`tifffile`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) library will read the series of images in the file and return it as a numpy array of shape 513x513x21.

To resize the numpy array to 375x500x21, use [`skimage.transform.resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) (or `scipy.ndimage.zoom`). It might be faster to resize the 21 channels separately.

To write a TIFF file containing a single multi-channel image of size 375x500x21 using `tifffile`, specify the `planarconfig` parameter. Not many libraries or apps can handle such files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't aware of this point "Instead the file contains 513 images of size 513x21."

Answer (score 1):

You can use **OpenCV** to resize your image. I was able to resize a TIFF format image using following code:

```
import cv2

file = "image.tiff"
img = cv2.imread(file)
print("original image size: ", img.shape)

new_img = cv2.resize(img,(img.shape[1]-100,img.shape[0]-100))  # cv2.resize(image,(width,height))
print("resized image size: ", new_img.shape)
```

Output:
original image size:  (512, 768, 3)
resized image size:  (412, 668, 3)

Opencv takes **INTER_LINEAR** as default interpolation method.

You can change interpolation by providing an additional argument

```
new_img = cv2.resize(img,(img.shape[1]-100,img.shape[0]-100),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Read more about available interpolation method here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize

Comment: Tried using opencv. But it gives me this error:   cv2.imread('new.tif')
[ WARN:0] OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples

Comment: Can you comment your opencv code? also can you provide your original image? I will try to run it on my end.

Comment: Here's the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1695sC1AvQQDQ8k02Phog0YSg1rP_7xIz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My open cv code is just two lines. It fails while trying to read the file. I guess, it's because of the number of channels in my image (i.e. 21 instead of 3). 

>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.imread('2009_003961_SEG.tif')
[ WARN:0] OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples

Comment: It looks like it maybe the problem with the opencv version. Version below 3.4.5 would give some sort of error. Try to upgrade it and try.

Comment: I am using opencv version  is '4.1.0'. Still doesn't work. I have done a workaround for now by downsampling each channel separately and then stacking them together.